# Bootstrap form columns are not aligned with non-form columns?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code  ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jazzblue/6a0ah2xz/1/) -  make sure you stretch the "demo" frame enough  that the buttons are on a single line):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UI-Compatible" content="IE=edge /">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 /">


  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

  <br/><br/><br/>

    <div class="row">         

      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">


           <label for="pfSel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Product Family:</label>

           <div class="col-sm-4">
             <select class="form-control" id="pfSel"></select>
           </div>

          <label for="pidSel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select PID:</label>            

          <div class="col-sm-4">
             <select class="form-control" id="pidSel"></select>
          </div> 

        </div>
      </form>

    </div>    

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
      <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>  
    </div>

  </div>

</body>
```

The first line is a form while the second line are buttons outside the form to indicate where columns are. As you can see the select drop-downs in the forms are not aligned with buttons below it. The drop-downs left borders are different in relationship to buttons. Why is this happening and is there any way to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row` elements add negative margins to account for the padding used in Bootstrap's `.col-*` definitions. `.form-horizontal` forms also do that, so you shouldn't wrap your `<form>` element inside `<div class="row">`.

Update your markup as follows:

```
<div class="container">       
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pfSel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select Product Family:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control" id="pfSel"></select>
            </div>

            <label for="pidSel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Select PID:</label>            
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <select class="form-control" id="pidSel"></select>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>
        <div class="col-sm-1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"></button></div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, use `margin` or similar CSS properties to add whitespace, not `<br />` tags.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/6a0ah2xz/2/)